# Can JNDI name be used in Spring @JmsListener destination?

Tags: spring, jms, jndi, spring-jms, spring-java-config

`Spring 4.2.4`, `WebSphere MQ 7.x` and `JBoss EAP 6.4`.

Consider the following `JmsConfig`:

```
@Bean
@Profile("all")
public ConnectionFactory devConnectionFactory() {
    ConnectionFactory cf = null;
    JndiObjectFactoryBean connection = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
    connection.setJndiName(connectionFactoryName);
    connection.setProxyInterface(ConnectionFactory.class);
    connection.afterPropertiesSet();
    cf = (ConnectionFactory) connection.getObject();            
    return cf;
}

@Bean
public JndiDestinationResolver jndiDestinationResolver() {
    JndiDestinationResolver jdr = new JndiDestinationResolver();    
    return jdr;     
}

@Bean
JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> jmsContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    factory.setConcurrency(getConcurrency());
    factory.setRecoveryInterval(new Long(getRecoveryInterval()));
    factory.setAutoStartup(new Boolean(this.getAutoStartup()));
    factory.setTransactionManager(this.jmsTransactionManager());
    factory.setSessionTransacted(true);
    factory.setDestinationResolver(jndiDestinationResolver());

    return factory;
}

@Bean
public JmsTransactionManager jmsTransactionManager() {
    return new JmsTransactionManager(this.devConnectionFactory());
}
```

And `JmsListener`:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "${jms.jndi.inqueue}", containerFactory = "jmsContainerFactory", selector = "version='001' AND eventtype is null")
public void onMessageVersion1(Message message) throws JMSException {
    BusinessLog.log("MQ inbound message", message);
    processMessageHeaderVersionMatched(message);
}
```

`${jms.jndi.inqueue}` is a JNDI name. I thought `JndiDestinationResolver` would be able to intervene and handle it correctly, however, that is not the case.

No exception or error occurs, but messages are not picked up from the Queue.

It may also be added that `Messages` can be successfully put on Queues using the same set up (`ConnectionFactory` JNDI look up).

Comment: In your JBoss server configuration file, have you set "<annotation-property-replacement>false</annotation-property-replacement>" to 'true'?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @tggm, I don't recall solving it.